# Circuit Breakers Tripping When Power Restored After Outage

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

We just finished construction of a new home in Washington State.  We've had several minor power outages in the couple of months that we've lived here - a few seconds to 10 or 20 minutes.  After a few of these outages I've found that a number of circuit breakers were tripped.  On one occasion I was able to check the box during the outage and found no tripped breakers, then checked it when power was restored and found multiple breakers tripped.  It's an Eaton panel, with apparently 3 different types of "special" breakers (i.e. breakers with added protection and test buttons).  The first photo shows the panel after one outage.  The second is a much clearer picture of the panel, with a yellow highlight beside each breaker that is tripped in the first photo.  A few observations I've made:

- only the "special" breakers are tripping.
- Nearly all the tripped breakers are on the same leg of the split phase supply - the lowest one looks to be on the other leg.
- The tripped breakers flash a code when turned back on which shows 5 flashes meaning they tripped due to a ground fault.
- It appears to be consistent that the same, or nearly the same, breakers trip each time - the "every other breaker" pattern is typical.
- We have a whole house surge protector, which is wired to the top left breaker.

We also have a separate workshop fed by a 200 amp service which has one of these "special" breakers, and it also trips in the same circumstance.  I have no way of knowing if it's on the same power leg.

[image]

[image]

The picture below shows the cables entering the house from the garage on the right.  The cables run together the length of the house, splitting away to each destination.  Of course only a couple of cables reach the far end (jet tub and master bedroom/bathroom).

[image]

The following photo is the main panel in the workshop.  It is fed by its own 200 A supply.  There is only one "special" breaker in the workshop and it has tripped several times on power restoration, while none of the coventional breakers have ever tripped.

[image]

Any thoughts on why these breakers are tripping, and how this can be fixed?

Comment: Oriented and brightened up that picture.  I broke it into 3 zones (breakers, labels and rest) and adjusted each differently, that's why it looks weird.  Now you can see trip flags and what color those breakers are, so you can see what kind they are.

Comment: Can you explain why the Jet Tub has two GFCI breakers for it? Does it really use two separate 120V circuits?  Also, how are the homeruns run out of this panel? Is there a large "trunk" of NM cable coming out bundled together, or do they all go off in separate directions, especially the homeruns for the circuits that are tripping?

Comment: I'll try to get a better picture today.  Yes, the jet tub has two separate 120 v circuits - one for the pump and one for the heater.  The home runs come out as a bundle of NM cables, and individual cables run out of that bundle to their destinations.  I don't see any pattern to where they come out of that bundle, for example the jet pump is at the far end, and those 2 cables go to receptacles right next to each other.  The dishwasher and disposal receptacles are in the same box.  Office plugs and printer are in the same room.

Comment: @Mark -- how far do the cables run bundled before going their separate ways?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - It's probably 20 or 25 feet from the panel to where the kitchen circuits head off, and another 40 feet or so to where the final cables head off to the master bedroom/bathroom including the jet tub.  I'll also add a picture which shows the "bundle" as it enters the house from the garage where the panel is.

Comment: I probably wouldn't characterize how those cables are run as "bundled" so much...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - That's why I posted the picture - just to be sure.

Comment: You may want to check the lighting in that room, it really flattens out the colors and makes your camera not see blue from green.  If it's real fluorescent, the tubes are quite old - the latest tubes have a CRI (Color Rendering Index of 90+.  You won't believe the light!! If it's LED, again low CRI, look for 80+ CRI LEDs. (90s are rare).

Comment: @Mark -- do the cables maintain spacing as they run down to the panel?

Comment: I would be checking the panel loading. A large imbalance on L1 vs L2 can cause issues and this problem. Motor loads if on at the time of the power interruption including Refridgeration circuits that are on all the time but not on the jetted tubs motor or garbage disposal unless they were in use or turned on. You may be able to recreate it by turning the main off and then back on but I don’t encourage this as it is hard on the breaker and the devices.  The best path forward is to verify the load on L1 &L2 because a large imbalance can cause issues that may be root cause.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - It's all buried in insulation now, but I took pictures of every wall in the house before drywall was installed and I can see those cables in several pictures. They don't appear any different, other than fewer cables as the various loads take off.

Comment: @EdBeal - The only large 120v load in use at the time would have been the refrigerator.  The jet tub, disposer, dishwasher, washing machine, bathroom heater, etc. were not running.  Loads in use were lighting (entirely LED), a couple computers (laptops and a small desktop - no bitmining operations here!), probably a flatscreen television, and a bunch of very small loads like phone chargers and clocks.

Comment: @EdBeal - Also, the workshop which has it's own 200 A service has one "special" breaker for lighting which also tripped.  The lights were all turned off at the time, and the only loads running were an alarm panel and security cameras.

Comment: @Mark -- can you get us a photo of the "special" breaker in the workshop?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I added the photo.  Much better lighting in the workshop than in the garage!  Is there a better term than "special" to describe these breakers? I gather there are at least three different kinds of special - blue, green, and white.  What do the colors mean?

Comment: @Mark -- if you unplug the fridge, turn the main breaker off, wait 10 minutes, then turn the main breaker back on while leaving the fridge unplugged, do the other nuisance trips still happen? (Trying to rule out anything about the fridge starting up as a cause for the problem -- of course, you'll want to plug the fridge back in when you're done with this test)